# How am I supposed to simplify this logarithm?

Tags: logarithms

Given is $$\log_6(a)=6$$

Simplify - $$\log_6 (1/a^7)$$ and the answer is supposed to be $-42$.

I don't understand what I'm supposed to do here?

Comment: There are identities about the logarithms of powers you have probably been taught that will help you here.

Comment: The answer would be exactly the same if you are given $\log_k a=6$ and are asked to compute $\log_k(1/a^7)$. The value of $k$ is irrelevant. It could be $6$ or $e$ or $1/2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT**

Recall that by definition

$$\log_6a=6 \iff 6^6=a$$

then

$$\log_6\left(\frac1{a^7}\right)=x \iff 6^x=\frac1{a^7}$$

or use that

- $\log x^n=n\log x$
- $\log \frac1x=-\log x$

Comment: So do I replace a with 46656 and rise it to the 7th power?

Comment: We have that $6^6=a\implies 6^{42}=a^7$. Can you conclude from here?

Comment: Ohhh yes thank you!

Comment: There is no need to go to the exponential; using $\log_6(a^{-7})=-7\log_6a$ is the best path.

Comment: That’s a way by the definition the other one is use the formula for logarithm which of course are deduced from the same definition, that is $$\log_6(1/a^7)=\log_6 (a^{-7})=-7\log_6 a=-42$$ but the application by the definition is much more useful if you need to get confident with that.

Comment: @egreg I’ve just explained my aim here above. If one asker can’t solve a trivial problem like that I think itbis not very useful to give a solution by some “magic” formula he/she needs to memorize. As first choice I highly prefer a solution based on the definition. Anyway I’ve also indicated the formulas you are referring to for the solution.

Comment: @gimusi That's not a “magic formula”, but an important consequence of the main property of the logarithm. Everybody ought to know that $\log(x^y)=y\log x$.

Comment: @egreg Yes of course, I’m referring to the asker’s perspective when I call it “magic”. I’m not claiming that the formula is not important (I’ve also indicated that)  but I think that it is more important to understand the properties from the basic definition insted to use a given formula. From there indeed one aquires the knowledge to prove those formulas and use that in a proper way.

Answer (score 2):

For any logarithm, $\log a^b=b \log a$, so in your case $$\log_6\frac 1{a^7}=-7\log_6a=-42$$
We don't have to solve for $a$ at all, though we could use $\log_6a=6$ to say $a=6^6$